# How can you fetch the rows for multiple pages in a single call of server in kendo grid?

Tags: c#, kendo-ui, grid, custompaging

In kendo grid paging, when we click the page number it calls the server and returns a set of data. Because of this the performance is very low. Instead, I need to call the server and get 50 rows at a time and the rows should be displayed in five pages in kendo grid.

Can anyone help with this?

Comment: If you tried anything about this before write your code please.

Answer (score 0):

please try to give  **ServerOperation(false)** for the grid it will take all the data at a time